# GPO: Startup PowerShell script on multiple OUs only running once

Tags: powershell, group-policy, startup-scripts

I have a weird issue with a PS script which should run on startup of a computer.
This script is configured identical on three levels (OUs) only different parameters.
Depending on for which hosts it's configured it should install certain things.
On some machines there are multiple OUs applied which should run the script with different parameters.
Looking at the output of `gpresult /h C:\gpo.html` it shows that all OUs are applied with the correct parameters from each OU.
As the script has logging enabled with the OU name as the log file name it is possible to differentiate them when they are run.

The problem now is that only one script from the highest OU is applied.
All the others are not even "called" as no log files (Transcipt wise) have been created.

So my question is what might be the reason that only one script is actually running but the others not?

Comment: `All the others are not even "called" as no log files (Transcipt wise) have been created.` What does Group Policy environment debug logging show?  https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/ask-the-directory-services-team/a-treatise-on-group-policy-troubleshooting-8211-now-with-gpsvc/ba-p/400304

Comment: Thanks for that explaination. I tried it and could see two scripts being called but one had some "elevation" issue, which wasn't quite correct as the problem was a parameter I removed a while ago which let the script fail right at the start.

But one script is not showing up (being called) inside the log.
It is actually the one on the "middle layer". So the "Default GPO level" works fine and the closest to the OU. 
WHat can I do to see what might be the issue here?

Comment: Move the "middle" GPO to another OU to see if it really is an issue with the OU or rather the settings inside the GPO.

Comment: Thx @DavidTrevor for the hint.
I've tried that already. Also I've tried:
- comparing the two OUs. Both are identical (except the script parameters)
- disabled and enabled alle these scripts in different constellations
- created a new test GPO
- checked permission via System account and tried the script parameters which were working perfectly fine

I'm all out of ideas by now.